# google apps script : get poi data out of map

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

I am new to the whole google app script and i might be missing something essential if so please forgive me.

Use Case:

I have a google map with POI on it gotten from my gps. The issue with these points is that they are all based on long and lati. By itself this works perfectly in google maps. But as we share this map with other people it sometimes provide a issue as they need a physical address.

So I was thinking that if i could pull out all the POI on the map and use the reverseGeocode I could create a spreadsheet with the name of the POI and the physical address and even the long and lati of the point.

But I just can't seem to find a way to get that data out of the map. Where I could use the DocumentApp.openById() or Spreadhseet .... there does not seem a way to actually get the maps loaded in.

If their is another way or if I am approaching this the wrong way please advice.

Comment: To better understand your question. You're using [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)? From Apps Script, Have you checked the method [newGeocoder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#newGeocoder()) from the [Class Maps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps) or the [Class Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder.html) ?

Comment: The issue is not so much to conversion of cords to addresses but getting the data of my own created maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get some data from an API not supported by Apps Script, you can use the [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app.html). You need just to pass the URL as a parameter in the [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app.html#fetch(String)) method or if you want to pass some advanced parameters, you can pass them as a JSON object in a second argument, defining it like [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app.html#fetchurl,-params).